# update acf field value using sql query?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Any example to update acf field value? I am newcomer in acf fields. I need to use sql code. the field is numeric and the name is “totalviews”. I want to update the totalviews by +1 using sql only without using any variables in php. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET meta_value=meta_value + 1 WHERE `meta_key`='totalviews' and post_id=123
```

Please note following:

1. **wp_** prefix is the standard prefix and might be different for you.
2. The **post_id** value is an assumption and depending on your previous transaction your actual value will be very different.

I hope this helps!!

Comment: yes this works, but i add the code in  javascript function in php which is triggered when i tap a button on my page to run it. Runs the first time and updates the database but the second time if i click again without refreshing the page does not work! the code run but does not update the database! why???? this is driving me crazy!

Comment: Couple of questions: 1. Why use sql only? 2. Why mix JS and PHP 3. Why not use wordpress ajax calls?

Comment: I cant update it two times without refreshing the page :( dont know how to make it update two times!

Comment: Read up on [Ajax in WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins). This will allow you to do a couple of things: a. Update multiple times without reloading the page. b. Increment value using WP and acf functions instead of direct sql.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your problem. You can try this

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value` = replace(meta_value, 'old_value', 'new_value') WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'your_key'
```

Hope this helps.