# SQL command query to update date of birth to age not valid

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm working on a wordpress custom projects, and I made this SQL command to update the user field mag_age to the age of user based on date of birth - mag_date_of_birth

mag_date_of_birth and mag_age are both ACF fields and its on the wp_usermeta table

this is the sql command that isn't working

```
UPDATE wp_usermeta
SET `wp_usermeta`.`meta_key` = 'mag_age' = DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), `wp_usermeta`.`meta_value` ='mag_date_of_birth')), '%Y') + 0;
```

SQL command source - [How to Calculate Age From Date of Birth in SQL?](https://www.scaler.com/topics/how-to-calculate-age-from-date-of-birth-in-sql/)

when I execute that command its tells me that Query OK, 97667 rows affected
but it logs out the administrator account and can't login anymore...can anybody tell me what's wrong on my sql command..

Note: We need this sql command so badly because we need to run this once every 1st day of the month to update the age.

Please help.

Comment: How many rows are there in the table. There might be a job running in the background which kills long running queries. If this is a one time query you could disable the job and execute the query if that is the issue/

Comment: we have 2,624 user on our wordpress user table including the admin account...no job running in the background...because this command we execute directly on phpmyadmin of course we have backup but my question here is, is it my sql query right...

Comment: I just saw my wp_usermeta table, when execute that command it clears the meta_key - screenshot here - https://imgur.com/a/T2tFMGD

Comment: Do you store age?

Comment: Hmm. I can never connect to imgur so cannot see your screen shot..everything pertaining to the question should be included in the question

Comment: @JayLee I am assuming you are trying to update the ACF fields. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56811597/update-acf-field-value-using-sql-query . This might help

Comment: Very strange SQL code. You assign to the column `meta_key` the result of comparing the string `'mag_age'` and the expression `DATE_FORMAT( ... ) + 0`.

Comment: If you need an age then use simple `TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, CURRENT_DATE)`

Comment: I think your query should use `WHERE meta_key = 'mag_age'` somewhere, not `SET meta_key = 'max_age' = ...`

Comment: You have no `WHERE` clause, so you're changing every row in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be setting the `meta_value` field, not `meta_key`. Use a `WHERE` clause to select the rows based on the key.

You can use a self-join to relate each user's `mag_age` and `mag_date_of_birth` rows.

```
UPDATE wp_usermeta AS m1
JOIN wp_usermeta AS m2 ON m1.user_id = m2.user_id
SET m1.meta_value = DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), m2.meta_value)), '%Y') + 0
WHERE m1.meta_key = 'mag_age'
  AND m2.meta_key = 'mag_date_of_birth'
```

Comment: Im on travel right now sir..so I will test this later.. Btw thank you..

Comment: Got an SQL error - Incorrect datetime value
my value in the is look like this = 19911207

Comment: can you correct date format function sir if ever, I think this function DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), m2.meta_value))  is only good if the date format is like this   - 1991-12-07,   but my data value in the database is without a hypen

Comment: I've changed the date of birth value and put hypens on it like this 1991-12-07 and it work....but thats not how ACF save the date on db it saves date without hypens like his 19911207, please help, I still need help on this sir...

Comment: You can use `STR_TO_DATE()` to parse dates in other formats. `STR_TO_DATE(m2.meta_value, '%Y%m%d')`

Comment: Thank you sir barmar...I already solved this with the help of your sql command...its working all the time...STR_TO_DATE() solved my problem...